what's the differences in topology?
so why when I add edges in the first image the edges go the side face when I join the last vertices, while in the second image the edges stop on the top face


Loop cut only works for quads. your bottom face is n-gon (more than 4 sides)

You looked at the first version and the second version, compared them and could not figure out what the difference between the last faces in both versions is? Counting vertices or edges is one of the simplest things which immediately shows a difference between them. Why did you not wonder that the top face is not cut?
